# Select Mysql to get Image url based on id

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am just creating a mysql query to get imagename from database, but i can't select on the right way. I want to get imagename based on ID of member at my website. I did try many times, but i failed many times. If anyone can help me.. Thank you very much then.

If i do this mysql query:

```
$GetBannerImageSql = $database->database_query("SELECT banner FROM banner_images WHERE banner_id='".$owner->user_info['user_id']."'");

$smarty->assign('bannerexists', $bannerexists);
$smarty->assign('GetBannerImage', $GetBannerImage);
```

I get:

```
resource(200) of type (mysql result)
```

And if i try this query:

```
$GetBannerImageSql = $database->database_query("SELECT banner FROM banner_images WHERE banner_id='".$owner->user_info['user_id']."'");
$GetBannerImage = $database->database_fetch_assoc($GetBannerImageSql);
var_dump($GetBannerImage);

$smarty->assign('bannerexists', $bannerexists);
$smarty->assign('GetBannerImage', $GetBannerImage);
```

I get this then:

```
array(1) { ["banner"]=> string(19) "banner-animated.gif" }
```

Second is fine, but its only imagename, but i dont see id.

Comment: Well, you are not _selecting_ the id in your statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PicturePath` (
  `ID` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0;

    --
INSERT INTO `PicturePath` (`ID`, `Path`) VALUES
(1, 'img/picture.png');
//End DB
// Start script


    $PictureID = $_GET['ID']; // example, user is navigating to http://www.mysite.com/Picture.php?ID=1

    $Get_Picture = $Conn->prepare("SELECT PicturePath FROM pictures WHERE ID=?");
    $Get_Picture->bind_param('i', $PictureID);
    $Get_Picture->execute();
    $Get_Picture->bind_result($Path);
    $Get_Picture->close();
    echo "<img src='$Path'></img>";
```

My example given is in MYSQLI, adapt this to your requirements

Comment: Thank you for your reply Daryl, but i use Smarty Php template engine. and on my tpl is it so:  <img id='ban_img' src='./uploads_user/1000/{$owner->user_info.user_id}/{$GetBannerImage}' it means to put all in one link. I want to select image name based on profile id of member and put that on tpl.

Comment: Modify the query above to search for the criteria that you want to, just experiment. I haven't got much experience with Smarty so I can't unfortunatly assist you further

Answer (score 0):

echo this... ->

```
  $GetBannerImage['banner']
```

It will return ...
  "banner-animated.gif"

Then use it in your template as needed.

Thanks!

@leo.

Comment: I solved it to create new php:

$answer = mysql_query("SELECT banner FROM banner_images WHERE banner_id='0'");

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($answer);
if ($numrows == 0) {
    $GetBannerImages = "";
} else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($answer)) {
        $i++;
        $GetBannerImage = $row['banner'];
        if ($i != $numrows) {
            $GetBannerImages .= $GetBannerImage . "";
        } else {
            $GetBannerImages .= $GetBannerImage;
        }
    }
}

But thank you all for your help!!